# how to access data in a cloudant doc using from node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloudant

I wrote the the below code in the index.html page of bluemix:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $("button").click(function() {
                var Cloudant = require('cloudant');
                var password = "#password";
                var myAccount = "#accountname";
                Cloudant({account:myAccount, password:password}, /* @callback */ function(err, cloudant,body) {
  if (err) {
    return ("Failed");
  } else {
                printTable(body);
}
  });
```

I want to get a document from cloudant database and display it in a table.

Answer (score 1):

To access Cloudant from Node.js you can use the Node.js API for Cloudant:

https://github.com/cloudant/nodejs-cloudant

The code below was copied from the README.md file from the about github directory.
It connects to cloudant, set the "animals" db for use and get the "dogs" documents:

```
var Cloudant = require('cloudant');
var me = 'nodejs'; // Replace with your account.
var password = process.env.cloudant_password;

Cloudant({account:me, password:password}, function(err, cloudant) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log('Failed to initialize Cloudant: ' + err.message);
  }

  var db = cloudant.db.use("animals");
  db.get("dog", function(err, data) {
    // The rest of your code goes here. For example:
    console.log("Found dog:", data);
  });
});
```

Also take a look at the Node.js Cloudant DB Web Starter Boilerplate available in Bluemix:

https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/nodejs-cloudant-db-web-starter/

It provides a sample application that connects to Cloudant and uses several methods of the API.

Comment: Thanks Alex for the answer. When I write this piece of code, I get a javascript error saying that "require is not defined". Can you please help me avoid this error.

Comment: Suchitra, this is just a piece of code, not the complete code. If you create the Node.js Cloudant DB Web Starter application in Bluemix and download the code, the app.js will have a more complete example. Also note this is Node.js server side code, not pure JavaScript client code (i.e not meant to be used in the index.html page you mentioned initially.